# when I use .innerText is undefined but when I don't it isn't

Tags: javascript, html

So im trying to get a `innerText` of an HTML element using JS but when I do that it tells me that my objects are undefined, but If I ask to log without `.innerText` it doesn't gives me an error and gives me the description of the `<p>` element I'm trying to get!

HTML:

```
     <div class="rTable"> 
        <div class="rTableRow"> 
            <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Producto</strong></div> 
            <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Preço</span></div> 
            <div class="rTableHead">Quantidade</div> </div>
            <div class="rTableRow"> 
            <div class="rTableCell">T-shirt World</div> 
                <div class="rTableCell">
                    <p class="cart-price">14,99$</p></div> 
            <div class="rTableCell"><input style="width:50px;height: 20px;" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" min="1">               
            <button class="btn-danger" >Remover</button></div> </div> 
            <div class="rTableRow"> 
            <div class="rTableCell">T-shirt World</div> 
            <div class="rTableCell"><p class="cart-price">14,99$</p></div> 
            <div class="rTableCell"><input style="width:50px;height: 20px;" type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" min="1" value="1">               <button class="btn-danger" >Remover</button></div> </div> 
         </div>
```

JS:

```
   function updateCartTotal(){
 var cartItemContainter = document.getElementsByClassName('rTable')[0]
 var cartRows = cartItemContainter.getElementsByClassName('rTableRow')



 for(var i = 0; i<cartRows.length; i++){

     var cartRow = cartRows[i]
     var priceElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('cart-price')[0]
     var quantityElement = cartRow.getElementsByClassName('quantity')[0]
     console.log(priceElement,quantityElement)
     var price = priceElement.innerText

     console.log(price)

 }
}
```

Comment: and where is the `innerText` in your code?

Comment: its on the cart-price <p>? I don't know

Comment: You are looping over _all_ of your `.rTableRow` elements here, but the first one does not contain any `.cart-price` or `.quantity` elements (because it is the _header_ row of your table.) `priceElement` and `quantityElement` are therefor `undefined`, and when you try and access `innerText` of _that_, of course you get an error.

Comment: sorry my bad I have updated the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error will be on the first row.
Please check your first row.

```
<div class="rTableRow"> 
    <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Producto</strong></div> 
    <div class="rTableHead"><span style="font-weight: bold;">Preço</span></div> 
    <div class="rTableHead">Quantidade</div> 
</div>
```

It has rTableRow class but there is no "cart-price" and "quantity" elements for the first row.
If you change the class name of this first row(title row), you will no have error.

Comment: Or make `for(var i = 0; …` into `for(var i = 1; …`